# Understanding performance optimizations of View Functions

Tags: evm, network, optimization

First I understand that view functions cost no gas and they are run locally on the node that gets the call. I am curious about practical optimizations of view functions.

To make things simple maybe a contrived example helps.

Assume there's a `Lottery.sol` contract that looks like this.

```
contract Lottery {
  # total number of tickets
  uint256 public ticketCount;

  # check if a ticket is claimable with a ticket ID
  mapping(uint256 => claimable) public isClaimable;
  
  # ...
}
```

Assume the ticketId's are incremented by one and there are unbound number of tickets.

Now you want to create script/contract/something that can check every ticket to see if it's claimable. I want to work through optimizations for this.

**Option 1: Do it all in Web3**

The first solution is to do it all in web3. Calling `ticketCount` then looping from `0` to `ticketCount` and calling `isClaimable` on each ticket.

The pros to this are it's simple, but the cons are you incur a huge amount of network overhead.

**Option 2: Do the iteration in another smart contract**

In this solution you could create a contract that interacts with the the `Lottery` calling `ticketCount` and then looping through a fixed page size of `isClaimable` tickets and returning `ticketId`'s of only the claimable tickets.

Pros of this is you make significantly fewer network calls. Cons are you increase the response time for any one ticket because you need to check an entire page before you get the answer for one.

---

I am trying to understand the performance of the EVM and how view functions are optimizable.

- Does the better option change if you are using a local node vs infura or alchemy?
- If option 2 is best how do you choose the correct page size?
- Do the specs (cpu/ram) of the physical node that your calls make it to effect the processing ability?

Comment: Can't answer your specific questions, but one of the benefits of calling the function repeatedly rather than having a looping construct in another contract is that notwithstanding that view functions are "free" they are still subject to gas limits, which means that an onchain function which runs too many loops may fail midstream.  I beleive the gas is calculated but not charged, but will still fail if the limit is exceeded.

Comment: Thanks - Another way to think about this is. Does the node that runs your "read" have an effect on execution time?

Comment: No, its not really a time limit, its a gas limit, which is based on the actual EVM code that runs, not on the machine it runs on.

Comment: So, if I run a lot of lookups and the node has 16 vs 8 cores they would preform the same.